# Possible to write Spring JPA Data Repository interfaces without Hibernate managing entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My application already using Spring caching to cache query results so I don't want any Hibernate caching. More precisely, I found that Hibernate keeps the returned entities in the persistence context and then whenever I do something more, it tried to auto flush these entities (even Hibernate finds there is no change at the end). To counter that, I need to call `entityManager.clear()` every time after I call some repository methods. How do I turn off Hibernate caching while using Spring caching + Spring JPA Data repository?

Here is an example repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, String> {
    @Cacheable
    Optional<Sample> findById(String id);
}
```

Comment: Hibernate comes with different types of Cache: First Level Cache: Hibernate first level cache is associated with the Session object. Hibernate `first level cache(persistence context)` is enabled by default and there is no way to disable it.

Comment: Don't use `@Cacheable` with entites, instead use the 2nd level caching mechanism of your provider. You cannot disable the first level cache as that basically is the `EntityManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was thinking the same :)

Comment: @M.Deinum May you share the reason? My application has been setup to use `@Cacheable`

Comment: If you use multiple `@Cacheable` annotations for the same entity or for collections it will result in caching multiple different instances of the managed entity. Which will lead to surprising results (like updates not being detected because an update was issued but not all caches were updated). When using the proper 2nd level caching from your JPA provider this isn't an issue as it will properlly manage the caching for you. so imagine a `findById` and `findByName` both using `@Cacheable` they will store different instances. When updating from the `id` the `by-name` cache doesn't have update.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to look up hibernates `StatelessSession`. it has no caching/persistence context whatsorever.

But other than that, I sense that your session may be scoped to big. If the session (and transaction) scope is only as small as possible the issue you are having should not really arise (entites remaining the persistence context for too long).

Are you doing batch work? if yes, dividing the batch work into smaller transactions or session interactions may be the way to go

Comment: Thanks. If you can provide a sample code how to use StatelessSession in Spring Data Jpa repository, then I can pick yours as the answer

Comment: You cannot use a `StatelessSession` with Spring Data JPA unless you are going to rewrite the `SimpleJpaRepository` or define a custom repository which does this. However doing so will also lead to other surprising side-effects like not auto persisting changes (which normally happens and is what you are running into).

Comment: you are right, I was under the impression that StatelessSession merely extends Session implementing operations as no-op.

@user1589188 can you elaborate whats your usecase? caching a mutable, possibly detatched entity seems kind of wrong. you are also bypassing any concurrency checks (optimistic locking) by exposing your local session entity via a global cache

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb (from me that is) don't use `@Cacheable` with JPA entities, this will almost always lead to surprising results/side-effects.

Imagine the following

```java
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, String> {
  
  @Cacheable
  Optional<Sample> findById(String id);

  @Cacheable
  Optional<Sample> findByName(String name);

}
```

Now when retrieving a `Sample` with the `findById` method and changing some properties on it, it will eventually be persisted. Now the `findById` cache has an updated instance of `Sample`.

Now there is no issue if the `findByName` cache didn't have the same `Sample` entity as it will be added, however if it did have the same `Sample` entity it would not have the updated record. Even if it references the same data it doesn't reference the same instance of the `Sample`.

Which would lead to surprising results. Now ofcourse you could make it so that when you call `save` (which isn't needed) that it will destroy all caches, but that kind of defeats the purpose of caching. Next to that what if someone doesn't call save, because it is a managed entity it will automatically persist.

So instead of using `@Cacheable` here you are better of using the [2nd level cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-config) from the JPA Provider, probably Hibernate. Which will take care of all these things.

Comment: OK I see your point. But instead of answering what I asked you are asking me not to do that. I am not sure if I should pick yours as the answer 